# How to link Access table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL database and I want to link an Access table in the SQL database. Most of the online articles and videos show how to link the two databases from Access but not from SQL. I want the access table linked in SQL database so that every time the table gets updated in Access, the table in SQL server gets updated as well. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like something is very wrong in the program. If you want to do this why not simply connect to sql server in the first place and get rid of the table in Access?

Comment: I cannot delete the table from Access database as there are other programs connected to that table. I just want to link the Access table from my SQL database.

Comment: No offense but why do you have other programs opening a single user database like Access to read tables? Can you change those to read from your sql server instead?

Comment: @SeanLange How is Access a single user database?

Comment: @nicomp unless they have made some major changes since the last time I had to work with Access the file would be locked when a user opened it and no other connections were allowed. Maybe it supports multiple ODBC connections but certainly not if the front end was open. Again, this may have changed but that is what I had to work with many years ago.

Comment: @SeanLange - that hasn't been true since I started working on Access as version 2. If you split the database into front and backend you can easily have multiple users accessing the same backend db and even the same table at the same time

Comment: @dbmitch then I stand corrected. I remember about 20 years ago (the last time I really had to do much with Access) having problems getting multiple connections to work until a user closed the database in the application. That may have been how we were dealing with it at the time also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. It's called a *Linked Server* and will link your Access database in SQL Server where you typically will create a view to read the Access tables to avoid the `DatabaseName..TableName` syntax otherwise needed.

However, it will probably not work for you because SQL Server will insist on opening the linked Access database *exclusively*, meaning that you cannot open it later from your Access application. And if you open it first in Access, an attempted reading from SQL Server will fail because SQL Server cannot get exclusive access.

You may argue, that a shared access should be possible, and connection parameters indicate this, but I haven't found a way to achieve this.

So, as others have mentioned, you may have turn this upside/down, and use, say, ODBC to link the SQL Server tables in your Access application, and then let this take care of the maintenance of the SQL Server tables.

Comment: Should not matter if SQL server opens the tables exclusive. Quite sure the SQL files are also opened exclusive. Users are connecting to SQL server, not the actual files. So all the files are exclusive locked and opened (the mdf files) by SQL server - but all users are connecting to SQL server, not those locked files. It is SQL server that is updating the files - not the users connected to SQL server.  If Linked server to access can be read/write, then the fact of exclusive lock by SQL server don't matter - it locks all the files it is working with - including the actual mdf SQL files.

Comment: Ah, I see you stated that THEN access would also not be able to open that same access file - my sorry here. So you are correct that Access will not be able to open the database at the same time. However, one then could and should simply link access to SQL server and not the access file with the data in it. In other words use SQL server linked tables to get at the access file and don't link Access to the access data file. Such a setup should work as you claim.

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this `(SQL SERVER) => (MS Access)`

and yes you are correct, it's called linked tabled in Ms Access. In order to link a table from another database, you must have

1. Correct drivers installed. (ODBC)
2. Know the login details of your SQL server and have sufficient permission in SQL server

Go to MS Access -> External data -> ODBC Databse -> link to the data source by creating a linked table ->

Now you can select a DSN file where your sql server credentials are saved, or you can make "new" and follow the steps to get connected to the SQL server.

Once connected, you will be presented with a list of all the tables from SQL server. Select the table you want to link and finish the wizard.

You now have SQL table connected in MS Access and can input data directly.

Comment: I wanted something vice versa. I wanted the access table in the SQL database, not the SQL table in Access database as you have described.

Comment: Tea bag first and then hotwater or vice versa, It doesn't really matter, both make tea :) Or are we talking about a x,y problem here? if other applications require to connect to ms access table, they can connect to the linked table or directly your sql table.

Comment: @krishKM you misinterpreted the question.